# How to compare text input to multiple strings?

Tags: java, boolean, string-comparison, boolean-operations

I want the following if statement to compare against multiple strings but when i compare against more than one it gives me the error message that I created. Below is the code which does not work.

The variables are test = 'c3400553' and test2 = 'c3400554'

```
if (!uname.getText().toString().matches("[cC][0-9]{7}") ||
     !uname.getText().toString().equals(test) ||
     !uname.getText().toString().equals(test2)
    ) {
   uname.setError("Incorrect ID Format");
}
```

Below is the code which works for one comparison.

```
String test = "c3400553";
...

if (!uname.getText().toString().matches("[cC][0-9]{7}") ||
         !uname.getText().toString().equals(test)
        ) {
          uname.setError("Incorrect ID Format" );
}
```

I don't understand what the issue is

Comment: Check your conditions. Make sure you use `&&` and `||` where needed. Also check the usage of `!` (not operator). Above all, provide a [mcve]

Comment: uname refers to an edit text field from user input

Comment: The condition in your "multiple string test" will always return true. It's a bit like (x != 1) || (x != 2) where what you really want is (x != 1) && (x != 2).In your case what you probably want is: (!uname.getText().toString().matches("[cC][0-9]{7}") && (!uname.getText().toString().equals(test) &&
            !uname.getText().toString().equals(test2)) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you either need to remove some `!`, or you need to replace your `||` by `&&`.

It depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you want the id to be declared incorrect if it doesn't match the format AND if it is not equal to `test` AND ALSO not equal to `test2`, then the solution is this :

```
if (!uname.getText().toString().matches("[cC][0-9]{7}") && 
    !uname.getText().toString().equals(test) &&
    !uname.getText().toString().equals(test2) ) {

      uname.setError("Incorrect ID Format" );
}
```

Otherwise, if what you want to do is to check whether uname matches the format, and is NOT equal to test and test2, then the problem is that you need to remove the `!` before comparisons with test and test2 :

```
if (!uname.getText().toString().matches("[cC][0-9]{7}") || 
    uname.getText().toString().equals(test) ||
    uname.getText().toString().equals(test2) ) {

     uname.setError("Incorrect ID Format" );
}
```